# How to make Accordion Content expande from bottom to top?

Tags: css

How i can make this Accordion Content to expand from bottom to top?
Basically the main theme here is that i building a site and i want to have in an area (a div) this accordion but i want to place it at the bottom of the page and then when i press the specific button (currently working!) to expand not like the classic way, but to the top. Beacause i am a first year student at college and this is my second site i just want to make it as light i can , so without the need of jquery or complex stuff i do not understand!

```css
article.accordion {
  display: block;
  width: 650px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 1px 0.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #666;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
article.accordion section {
  display: block;
  width: 615px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}
article.accordion section h2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ddd;
}
article.accordion section h2 a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0 none;
}
article.accordion section,
article.accordion section h2 {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
article.accordion section:target {
  height: 450px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
article.accordion section:target h2 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab"></div>
<div id="connect">
  <p>
    <img src="images/Steam Dial.png" width="88" height="29">
  </p>
</div>
<div id="apDiv2">
  <article class="accordion">
    <section id="acc1">
      <h2>Games</h2>
      <p>This content appears on page 1.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="acc2">
      <h2>Software</h2>
      <p>This content appears on page 2.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="acc3">
      <h2>Hardware</h2>
      <p>This content appears on page 3.</p>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: SO needs a little knowledge ... I don't see any effort from your part to make the accordion work. Did you know JS ? You would need that to acomplish your goal.

Comment: learn how to script front end web before attempting this. even the basics.

Comment: were i can find that knowledge, should i go and buy  a book about css? or java? and also i need java to do that? thank you all!